# The requested URL was not found on this server or localhost redirected you too many times

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have Codeigniter version 3.1.10. when I hit "http://localhost/test" it will redirect to "http://localhost/test/user" and it shows in a browser like an image below.[image]

so, I added a .htaccess file with the below code. **test** is my project folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /projFolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/index.php/$1 [L]
```

now, it shows like "This page isn’t working, localhost redirected you too many times.". I tried too many things with .htaccess but not any success.

Comment: Could you please provide info from which URL to which URL you want to serve internally?

Comment: it just "default_controller". or just first or home page

Comment: So you mean you want like `http://your_domain/` to be served by link `http://your_domain/projFolder/test/index.php/$1`? Its not clear if you could give the sample URLs in your question like from frontend what URL you are hitting and backend which url it will serve in your question(like I mentioned) that will make things more clear, cheers.

Comment: when I hit "http://localhost/test" it will redirect to "http://localhost/test/user" and shows 404. so i add .htaccess file. i can add "default_controller" and User.php controller if it helps.

Comment: so you mean whatever uri has /test you want to point it to `test/user` correct? where you have files in user directory in backend?

Comment: the project already built I just take it from the live server and configure it in the localhost. I see "$route['default_controller'] = 'dashboard';" in routes.php...so, I checked Dashboard.php controller but when i echo "string"; exit(); work on construct() but not in index() method

Comment: <?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {
    exit('No direct script access allowed');
}
require(APPPATH . 'sendgrid/vendor/autoload.php');

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "vvv"; exit();
        parent::__construct();
        $this->session->set_userdata('parents1', 'on');
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo "sdff"; exit();
    }

Comment: above is Dashboard.php controller

Comment: I don't know how "localhost/test" is pointing to "localhost/test/user". where it's code could be?

Comment: I am sorry if its not htaccess related I am not an expert in codeignitoer or php, may be other experts could help here, cheers and happy learning, temporary comment.

Comment: htaccess was not in the live server I added in localhost because it was not running...btw thank you for the effort.

Comment: are you make shore to create the index() function on that User class if not then which you are created , you type that name in route.php file after class name..

Comment: Index function is there in User class...I also tried echo exit in index function but execution not reaching there